# Mouse mover sobre um item e um evento ser gerado WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Estou com dificuldade em implementar um efeito onde quando passo o mouse sobre o mouse sobre o item na tela o speed deve ser 0. E sem o mouse em cima deve voltar a ser 30. Uso WPF usando estrutura MVVM, então os eventos não podem estar na classe Classe.xaml.cs
Preciso de uma ideia sobre o assunto. Obrigada!

```
<common:BrnN Grid.Row="1"
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                                 Speed="30"
                                 Background="Black">
                <common:BrnN.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Background="Transparent"
                                BorderThickness="0"
                                Margin="20, 0"
                                Padding="0"
                                Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=common:BrN}, Path=DataContext.TagCommand}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding}">

                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Descricao}"
                                           Foreground="Gold"
                                           FontSize="18"
                                           FontWeight="Semibold" />
                                <TextBlock Text=": "
                                           Foreground="Gold"
                                           FontSize="18"
                                           FontWeight="Semibold" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Valor, StringFormat=F2}"
                                           Foreground="Gold"
                                           FontSize="18"
                                           FontWeight="Semibold" />

                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </common:BrnN.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Pesquise por "wpf event to command".

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar eventos no codigo associados ao elemento em questão. Usei um botao com o nome `bt_teste` pra exemplificar o que estou dizendo e os evento a seguir.

```
    private void Bt_teste_MouseLeave(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        bt_teste.Content = "fora";
    }

    private void Bt_teste_MouseEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        bt_teste.Content = "sobre";
    }
```

Comment: Eu fiz esta opção também, no entanto. Não esta funcionando perfeitamente. O comportamento não funciona da maneira que gostaria . 

** Coloquei no gridRow o mouse enter e mouse leave e estão acontecendo meio que as duas coisas juntas. Alem de congelar todos os  itens em um unico ponto eles nao voltam a rodar na tela

** Coloquei nos botões o mouse enter e o mouse leave e estao  acontecendo os dois eventos juntos. Alem de congelar todos os itens num unico ponto ele não volta a rodar